# Wait till animation is done in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have the example code from here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html

I would like to wait till the animation is done, my approach is to wrap the code in a promise and resolve true, when the animation is finished.
Not sure if there is a better approach

```
async function flash(point: Point, store: EditorStore) {
    const map = store.mapController.map;
    const layer = store.viewState.renderer.interactionMapLayer;
    const feature = new Feature(point);

    const start = Date.now();
    const flashGeom = feature.getGeometry()?.clone();

    if (!flashGeom) {
        return;
    }

    layer.getSource()?.addFeature(feature)

    const listenerKey = layer.on('postrender', async (event) => {
        const result = await animate(event, layer, flashGeom, map, start)
        if (result) {
            unByKey(listenerKey);

            map.getView().animate({
                duration: 1000,
                center: point.getCoordinates(),
                zoom: 22,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Code from example:

```
function animate(event: RenderEvent, layer: VectorLayer<VectorSource<Geometry>>, flashGeom: Geometry, map: Map, start: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        if (!flashGeom) {
            return resolve(false)
        }

        const duration = 1000;
        const frameState = event.frameState;

        if (!frameState) {
            return resolve(false)
        }

        const elapsed = frameState.time - start;
        if (elapsed >= duration) {
            //unByKey(listenerKey);
            return resolve(true)
        }
        const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
        const elapsedRatio = elapsed / duration;
        // radius will be 5 at start and 50 at end.
        const radius = easeOut(elapsedRatio) * 50 + 5;
        const opacity = easeOut(1 - elapsedRatio);

        const style = new Style({
            image: new CircleStyle({
                radius: radius,
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')',
                    width: 5 + opacity,
                }),
            }),
        });

        vectorContext.setStyle(style);
        vectorContext.drawGeometry(flashGeom);

        // tell OpenLayers to continue postrender animation
        map.render();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers-documentation states that you can simply pass a function as the second argument to the `animate`-method, which works as a callback-function:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#animate

> If you provide a function as the last argument to the animate method, it will get called at the end of an animation series. The callback will be called with true if the animation series completed on its own or false if it was cancelled.

here is a minimal working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/openlayers-animate-callback-h3d9tz?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I'm not talking about the view animation but feature animation. I wan't to wait til the feature animation is done and then start the zoom.

Comment: oh, my bad, got confused by the multiple `animate` in the code. That being said, wrapping the animation into a promise sounds like a clean approach, are there any complications with the existing code? I think, even returning a normal `setTimeout` with the same duration as the animation might be sufficient

Comment: no problem, there is no issue with the promise, just looking for improvements